# Ativando Conexão com Internet em uma Aplicação Android

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de saber uma forma de identificar se o celular android está conectado a internet independente se for rede móvel da operadora do celular ou wifi, e caso não esteja conectado, eu ativar todas as conexões tanto wifi como dados moveis.

**Obs:** Eu sei como verificar se o wifi está ativo e como ativa-lo, só não sei ainda os dados moveis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para saber qual é o estado de uma ligação à rede é necessário obter um objecto do tipo [NetworkInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html).
A forma de o conseguir é recorrendo à classe [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) obtida da seguinte forma:

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Um dispositivo *Android* tem vários tipos de ligação à rede disponíveis, entre eles [TYPE_MOBILE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#TYPE_MOBILE) e [TYPE_WIFI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#TYPE_WIFI).

Para testar se um determinado tipo está disponível pode utilizar o seguinte método:

```
public static boolean isNetworkConnected(ConnectivityManager connectivityManager, int type){
    final NetworkInfo network = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(type);
    if (network != null && network.isAvailable() && network.isConnected()){

        return = true;
    } else {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Por exemplo para saber se tem ligação 3G/4G:

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
boolean isConnected = isNetworkConnected(manager, ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
```

Normalmente o que se usa é obter a ligação activa através de:

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo network = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

boolean isConnected = network != null && network.isConnected() && network.isAvailable();
```

Para saber qual é o nome da ligação activa use:

```
String connectionName = network.getTypeName();
```

Não esquecer a permissão necessária:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Não existe isso de *"activar a ligação ao dados moveis"*, o que se activa é a ligação à *network/internet*.

O tipo de ligação activa, aquela que é retornada por `manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();` é, dentro das disponíveis, a que menor custo tem para o usuário. Se estiverem disponíveis a **TYPE_MOBILE** e a **TYPE_WIFI** a activa é **TYPE_WIFI**.

Answer (score 1):

Para verificar se a está conectado à Internet independente da interface pode ser usado o seguinte código:

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    boolean internetDisponível = netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected();
```

Ao invés de usar `isConnected()` também pode ser usado `isConnectedOrConnecting()` caso queira saber se ainda está tentando conectar.

Agora para ativar a 3G (dados móveis) é necessário usar a API Reflections do Java, pois não pode ser ativada por meio da API do Android. Então segue o código como ativar:

```
private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) {
    final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
    final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
    iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
    final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
    final Class iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
    final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);

    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
}
```

É preciso declarar no `AndroidManifest.xml` que você vai verificar o estado da conexão e mudá-la respectivamente:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```